# Why may the Java compiler change the happens-before order in a constructor?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, javac, java-memory-model

I've just read an [article about immutability in Java by Jeremy Manson](http://jeremymanson.blogspot.co.at/2008/07/immutability-in-java-part-2.html) and I'm a little bit confused about one thing: He gives this example of a `String` implementation:

```
class String {

  static String lastConstructed;

  private final byte[] bytes;

  public String(byte[] value) {
      bytes = new byte[value.length];
      System.arraycopy(value, 0, bytes, 0, value.length);
      lastConstructed = this;
  }

}
```

The point in this example is that `bytes` must be set **before** the instance of the String "escapes" the constructor by being accessible via `lastConstructed`. He then argues that this is not safe because *"The compiler can take the assignment to `lastConstructed`, and move it to before the assignment to `bytes`"*

But why is the compiler allowed to do this? Isn't that changing the happens-before order of the application? And if the compiler is really allowed to do that: in which scenarios is it allowed to do so? When must I take this happens-before order switching into account?

Comment: Yes, it can do it. And even if the compiler didn't, the CPU could. The only way to get a happens-before relationship when dealing with multiple threads is to formally establish a formal happens-before edge (using `volatile` fields, synchronization, etc).

Comment: There isn't a happens-before guarantee here.

Comment: @yshavit Is the happens-before order only not guaranteed for other threads or even for the same thread? And in which scenarios is the happens-before order not guaranteed?

Comment: Within each thread, actions that appear first in the code happen-before other actions. In other words, within a thread, you never need to worry about reorderings.

Comment: And why do I need to worry about reorderings in multiple-threads?